# I get this error trying to serve my first Angular page

Tags: angular, angular-cli

[**Error**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGcLL.png)

I am getting this error when I try to serve my first angular app

"ng server -o"

in the CLI. Please refer the image for details of the error.

Comment: [error] Error: spawn EPERM
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:403:11)
    at Object.spawn (child_process.js:553:9)
    at baseOpen (C:\Users\razeez\source\repos\ExpensesCLIENT\ExpensesClient\node_modules\open\index.js:205:34)
    at async MergeMapSubscriber.project (C:\Users\razeez\source\repos\ExpensesCLIENT\ExpensesClient\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\builders\dev-server\index.js:220:21)

Comment: Since this seems like a problem with some permissions, you can try to run it from an elevated ("run as administrator") command prompt.

Comment: I do not have this 'luxury' at work. Thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: @tromgy Is there a way i can serve this without admin rights ?

Comment: You should be able to, but it's not clear what permission exactly it lacks. I wonder if you Angular CLI was installed globally and thus requires admin privileges?

Comment: @tromgy Thank you for the for the keyword 'globally'. This helped solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

npm **run-script** ng serve -o

This enabled me to run the local cli